# Issue with Youtube API V3 with special characters in youtube URL

Tags: html, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am new to this youtube API.
I tried using different kinds of youtube URLs but the only one that is bugging me is the one containing special characters (/, _ etc) like-

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXYiU_JCYtU.

When i try to embed this url in iFrame, getting this issue.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bps0.png)

This is the embed code i took from google to show it in the page

`<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kXYiU_JCYtU" title="CASTLE OF GLASS [Official Music Video] - Linkin Park" allow='autoplay'> </iframe>`

I tried adding few iFrame properties but still no luck.

`<iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/kXYiU_JCYtU' title='CASTLE OF GLASS [Official Music Video] - Linkin Park' allow='autoplay; encrypted-media' referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts" rel="noopener external"> </iframe>`

Finally I tried the Youtube iFrame api but still same result.
[Youtube iFrame API error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4MUN.png)

I just want the iFrame to display the videos just like they are visible in youtube.

Comment: How exactly is this related to the YouTube api.   Looks like you are just trying to show a video in an iframe

Comment: Hi @LindaLawton-DaImTo, I even tried iFrame API of youtube and got the same result. I will modify the question to include it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your iframe syntax with my own video id that contains an underscore character. It worked fine. There must be something else causing this issue for you.

Does your video have embedding enabled?
See https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780

If that is not the problem, look for any other setting that may be different compared to other videos that do play correctly using a YouTube 'embed' URL.

BTW... Using a YouTube 'embed' URL is not the same as using the YouTube API. The YouTube API is an application programming interface - a set of libraries used by software developers. See https://developers.google.com/youtube